# Remove part of a string using regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex, replace, rss

I have a RSS reader in C#, my problem is that some sites also show a picture in their feeds, but I don't need it. This is how the description of a news from this site looks now:

```
/calcio/calciomercato/2013/09/01-271389/Calciomercato?rssimage This is the actual news...
/calcio/calciomercato/2013/08/01-271389/Notizia?rssimage This is the real news...
/calcio/calciomercato/2013/05/01-271389/Esempio?rssimage The news...
```

How can i remove all the text before the actual news? All the "undesired parts" end with "?rssimage" so how can I remove all the text before? And also, how can I check if a news contains this undesired text?

Thank you!

EDIT:
This is the RSS:
http://tuttosport.feedsportal.com/c/34178/f/619230/index.rss

This is the desided output:
Gli emiliani vogliono un attaccante: il sogno resta Belfodil, un'ipotesi concreta è Floro Flores, ma c'è anche il cileno dell'Universidad

I biancoscudati sognano il grande colpo: operazione però difficile perchè Sartori dovrebbe poi trovare il sostituto proprio in extremis

L'attaccante finora è stato poco impiegato tra i titolari, potrebbe andare a fare esperienza: i friulani lo hanno proposto al Bologna a titolo temporaneo

Comment: try to show the desire output you want to get

Comment: Can you post a *real* rss and the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
string input = "/calcio/calciomercato/2013/09/01-271389/Calciomercato?rssimage This is the actual news...";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(.*?)\?rssimage ", string.Empty);
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` at the op of your code file.

Comment: @user1100421 - This is what you wanted, not sure if it's what you needed. ;)

Comment: @Corak Well said, people complicate things themselves. This is where `XY` problem arise

Answer (score 3):

It's so simple that we don't need `Regex`, just some `string methods`:

```
int i = line.IndexOf("?rssimage");
if(i != -1) line = line.Substring(i+8).TrimStart();
```

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."